# Sort list by two fields doesn't work typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

I have a list with items in typescript:

```
let productList = [
   {active: false, location: 2, description: "test 123"},
   {active: false, location: 15, description: "test 123"},
   {active: false, location: 40, description: "test 123"},
   {active: false, location: 15, description: "test 123"},
   {active: false, location: 1, description: "test 123"},
   {active: true, location: 2, description: "test 123"},
   {active: false, location: 2, description: "test 123"},
   {active: false, location: 7, description: "test 123"},
   {active: false, location: 1, description: "test 123"}
 ]
```

I want to sort this list so I show on top the the items that has `active: true` and that have same location for example `location: 0`

I tried this it sorts by active on top:

```
productList.sort((a, b) => (b.active - a.active));
```

Now I want to add location too so those with same location are sorted one after other, one of my tries was this but no success:

```
productList.sort((a, b) => (b.active - a.active)&& ((a.location === b.location) ? 1 : -1) );
```

My end result I want to have is to show active on top and show immediately after those with same location as active

```
let productList = [
   {active: true, location: 2, description: "test 123"},
   {active: false, location: 2, description: "test 123"},
   {active: false, location: 2, description: "test 123"},
   {active: false, location: 1, description: "test 123"},
   {active: false, location: 1, description: "test 123"},
   {active: false, location: 7, description: "test 123"},
   {active: false, location: 15, description: "test 123"},
   {active: false, location: 15, description: "test 123"},
   {active: false, location: 40, description: "test 123"},
 ]
```

Can someone help me please? I'm  stuck. I tried several ways but not success.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your first condition to check if ***any*** of the elements that match the current `a` and `b` locations are active, not just the currently iterated elements. Here using [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
let productList = [
  { active: false, location: 2, description: "test 123" },
  { active: false, location: 15, description: "test 123" },
  { active: false, location: 40, description: "test 123" },
  { active: false, location: 15, description: "test 123" },
  { active: false, location: 1, description: "test 123" },
  { active: true, location: 2, description: "test 123" },
  { active: false, location: 2, description: "test 123" },
  { active: false, location: 7, description: "test 123" },
  { active: false, location: 1, description: "test 123" }
];

const hasActive = (o) => Number(productList.some(e => o.location === e.location && e.active));

const compare = (a, b) => (
  hasActive(b) - hasActive(a)
  || a.location - b.location
  || b.active - a.active
);

console.log(productList.sort(compare));
```

The above is very inefficient as it has two nested `some()` calls that iterate the complete array on every iteration. To help this you can either create a cache of results as in the first example below, or group the full array by location before sorting as in the second.

```js
const productList = [{ active: false, location: 2, description: "test 123" }, { active: false, location: 15, description: "test 123" }, { active: false, location: 40, description: "test 123" }, { active: false, location: 15, description: "test 123" }, { active: false, location: 1, description: "test 123" }, { active: true, location: 2, description: "test 123" }, { active: false, location: 2, description: "test 123" }, { active: false, location: 7, description: "test 123" }, { active: true, location: 1, description: "test 123" }];

const compare = () => {
  const activeCache = {};

  const hasActive = (o) => (
    activeCache[o.location] ??= Number(productList.some(e => o.location === e.location && e.active))
  );

  return (a, b) => hasActive(b) - hasActive(a)
    || a.location - b.location
    || b.active - a.active;
};

console.log(productList.sort(compare()));
```

A more involved solution which first groups by location, then sorts and maps back to an ungrouped array.

```js
function groupSort(arr) {
  const grouped = {};
  
  for (const object of arr) {
    const { location, active } = object;
    grouped[location] ??= { location, hasActive: active, objects: [] };

    grouped[location].objects.push(object);
    if (active) {
      grouped[location].hasActive = true;
    }
  }

  return Object.values(grouped)
    .sort((a, b) => b.hasActive - a.hasActive || a.location - b.location)
    .flatMap(({ objects }) => objects.sort((a, b) => b.active - a.active));
};

const productList = [{ active: false, location: 2, description: "test 123" }, { active: false, location: 15, description: "test 123" }, { active: false, location: 40, description: "test 123" }, { active: false, location: 15, description: "test 123" }, { active: false, location: 1, description: "test 123" }, { active: true, location: 2, description: "test 123" }, { active: false, location: 2, description: "test 123" }, { active: false, location: 7, description: "test 123" }, { active: true, location: 1, description: "test 123" }];

const sorted = groupSort(productList);

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: that's not a problem cause I will always have only one active element, but I'm getting error 'The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.' on this line ' productList.some(e => b.location === e.location && e.active) - productList.some(e => a.location === e.location && e.active)'

Comment: this issue is on typescript

Comment: You just need to explicitly convert the returned boolean to a number, so `+productList.some(e => b.location === e.location && e.active) - +productList.some...`